# rsync and ssh hangs without throwing an error or disconnecting

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync

I am trying to create an offsite backup using rsync and ssh in a MacOS environment. The problem is that at a random point during the transfer process, rsync will hang but never disconnect or throw an error. Viewing the active processes on the remote machine shows rsync and sshd start to use 0% CPU when this happens.

Here's an an example of the last line of verbose output before I quit the transfer using ^C:

```
<f+++++++ Audio/Sample Library/Kontakt Libraries/ANALOG STRINGS/Samples/AS_003.nkc
 475.99K 100%    2.28MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#4, to-check=310046/539375)
```

No error is thrown, and to start successfully transferring again, I have to reboot the remote machine.

Are there configurations I'm missing that can maintain a stable connection for a large rsync transfer?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the SSH configuration and add the ClientAliveInterval directive.
Maybe the connection is dropped at some point for unknown reason. Worth to try.

Also, when the transfer hangs, is the connection still active ? (from netstat do you see the connection as established)

Nothing in the logs ? And I mean all the logs, not only the one from SSH, there is no error message ?